# Custom validation in grails not working

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a simple code for custom validation in grails but don't know why its not working ???

I have a domain class Person with 2 fields nationality and other .The condition goes like if the user selects nationality as others which is an `inList` , then the other field is made mandatory and if user skips this field grails errors message should be raised .

```
nationality(blank:false,nullable:false,inList:["Indian", "Other"])
other(blank:true,nullable:true,validator:{val,obj ->
    if(obj.nationality!="Indian" && !val){println "values"+val+"nationality"+obj.nationality
    return ['requiredfield'] 
    }
```

I have also mapped the name of error in `message.properties` file as mentioned below

```
person.nationality.requiredfield=Please mention your nationality.
```

The output on console is values null nationality Others

Comment: What the issue you are facing, As I can see the code working fine.

Comment: "The output on console is values null nationality Others" values will not be null once it is set.

Comment: The code works fine but does not prints the error message as defined in message.property file

Comment: Where you do your validation, try println obj.errors to see the combinations of errorcodes.

Comment: on using obj.errors it prints grails.validation.ValidationErrors :0 errors

Answer (score 2):

You are placing error message at wrong place:

do this :

```
person.other.requiredfield = Please mention your nationality.
```

Note the difference in error code i.e replace "nationality" with "other".

Comment: nationality is an inList it has a selected value Others ,I want a error message if user doesn't fill the other field

Comment: You should take a look at http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/grails-arguments-in-custom-validator-error-message/

Comment: nothing works in my case I tried with all both the 2 methods but it failed to print the error message

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to provide a fully-qualified name in `messages.properties`?

So something like:

```
com.domain.Person.other.requiredfield = Please mention you nationality
```

Comment: Yes i tried with   return "com.in.service.Person.other.error" and in messages file I updated as com.in.service.Person.other.error=Somemessage

Comment: No, you should use full name in *messages.properties* and leave _requiredfield_ in the return statement. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes i tried with return ['requiredfield'] and in messages.properties  file I updated as com.in.service.Person.other.error=Somemessage and also with error.com.in.service.Person.other=Somemessage .But none of them works :-(

Comment: Why do you use _error_ at the end? The syntax is `full.package.name.ClassName.fieldName.returnedValue`. So in your case it would be `com.in.service.Person.other.requiredfield`. Still does not work?

Comment: I saw it in some link , anyways I have been using it in the conventional way only that is requiredfield at the end but was just checking the other way out  .But none of them works.